# Fourier integrals of rational functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been given a function $f(z) = \frac{e^{2iz}}{(z^2+1)(z^2+9)}$ and have so far found the poles and calculated residues lying within the upper half-plane. I've also shown by using the triangle inequality that when $|z| = R>3$ and $Im z \ge 0$, $|f(z)| \le \frac{1}{(R^2-1)(R^2-9)}$. Using these and by integrating around a semicircular contour in the upper half plane I have found the value of the integral $\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{e^{2iz}}{(z^2+1)(z^2+9)} = \frac{\pi}{24}(3e^{-2}-e^{-6})$.

The final part of the question is to deduce that $$\int_{0} ^\infty \frac{cos2x}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)} = \frac{\pi}{48}(3e^{-2}-e^{-6})$$

I see how the equation relates to the original complex function and I see that $cos2x$ is simply the real part of $e^{2ix}$. And therefore the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is the value I already have. What I fail to see is why does this equate to half that when I take the integral from $0$ to $\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the integrand is an even function,

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos 2x}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos 2x}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}dx = \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{2ix}}{(x^2+1)(x^2+9)}dx. $$

Comment: Fantastic thank you! This is what I had thought but wasn't all that sure. Many thanks!